# Why role do the display and content properties play in a clearfix

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is the definition of bootstrap 4's clearfix,

```
.clearfix::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
```

I understand what clear does but not the other two.

Why do we need to add an empty string and make it block?

I've sometimes seem display set to table as well, what does that do?

Comment: are sure it's on bootstrap 4?

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719148/8620333 (explaining why you need block)

Comment: Yep, copied it from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/clearfix/

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067918/why-do-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-require-a-content-property (explaining the content)

Answer (score 0):

`content: "";` means that you are forcing the clearfix element to have empty content. It is similar to the difference between 0 and null— without the empty content, it defaults back to `content:none;` which is not what we want here, as it won’t apply the style.

Similarly, the default value of the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements is actually `display: inline`. Giving them block is what will render them in the desired place.